# .Override method of different class

Tags: android, eclipse, class

Calling `onBackPressed` method of `Activity class` on a `View Class`? is it possible? and so how can I? thanks for help

**UPDATE**: I just created the GameView of my Game which is extends to `View Class`. I create a variable that increments whenever I finish every level so it will limit a levels per game. And so I want to implement a `onBackPressed method` which I can set the incrementing variable back to zero whenever the player press the back key.

`FULL CODE:` **MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
private GameView mGameView;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mGameView.interceptBackPressed()) {
        return;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    mGameView = (GameView) findViewById(GameView.countmaze);
```

Afterwards it goes to **Menu Class**

```
public class menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
static int nextmaze;
int countmaze = 0;
GameView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //I have here an AlertDialog builder
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LEVEL 1",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startnextmaze();

    }
}
void startnextmaze() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Intent game = new Intent(menu.this, Game.class);
    nextmaze = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
    Maze maze = MazeCreator.getMaze(nextmaze);
    game.putExtra("maze", maze);
    startActivity(game);
}
```

Then on my **GameView Class**

```
public class GameView extends View {
static int countmaze;

//Big codes here......

public boolean interceptBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    countmaze = 0;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to suggest good approach if you tell what you did so far and what you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you post your code and show how Activity is integrated with GameView it will be much easier to give you precise answer.

Comment: sir @Loop I think I cant do chatting on my reputation score. if you dont mind can we just continue chatting on facebook? Im badly needing your help. thanks in advance ! (https://www.facebook.com/j0naldCruz)

Comment: I don't have a facebook account. I have updated my answer with extra comment. It can't get more simple than that.

Comment: still having problem on mGameView = (GameView)fVBID(R.id.gameview) since gameview doesn't exist and i dont have xml layout on my GameView Class.

Comment: So how did you create GameView so far? I assume it was working, right?

Comment: yes finally it work. thank you so much for your time sir @Loop ! godbless. happy codings :) please vote for this one also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code with the following changes:

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private GameView mGameView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //View reference to object defined in XML
        mGameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.gameview);//id must be specified in XML
        //I assumed that GameView is a part of your XML layout

        //View created programmatically.
        mGameView = new GameView(this);

       //Use one of the above initialisation techniques of mGameView.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //here we are calling method on mGameView which cannot be null
        //that's why we initialised it in onCreate() method
        if (mGameView.interceptBackPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();//finish your Activity
    }
}
```

**GameView**

```
public class GameView extends View {

    public boolean interceptBackPressed() {
        //TODO handle your game logic here and return true if you don't
        //want your game to be shutdown, otherwise return false
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: is the `interceptBackPressed` method will be my new onBackPressed?

Comment: Yes, this is where you will decrease your variable to 0. By default pressing back destroy activity so this method must return true to avoid it.

Comment: Im just getting an error on the R.id. where do I declare it?

Comment: I leave `mGameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.gameview);` in a comment. And follow all the codes. But my function on the interceptBackPressed() didn't work.

Comment: R.id and R.layout are examples. You have to define id for your view in XML. If you create GameView programatically then refer to that object instead calling findViewById. This is a really basic stuff. Consider checking out some Android tutorials.

Comment: Yes it was created programatically. so I need to set the Id of the GameView Class instead of using findViewById? is yes how?

Comment: I don't see GameView created programatically, you call findViewById. Show your original code. Regarding ID, it's used to find view and get reference. If you create GameView programmatically calling new GameView() then you already have a reference and you don't need to search it with ID.

Comment: Actually I just follow your suggested `block of codes` on that. and as GameView.countmaze where `countmaze` is my incrementing variable on GameView Class. And now I change it in `mGameView.setId(1)` then `mGameView.findViewById(1)` and my program cant start and it forces to close

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59357/discussion-between-loop-and-icecream).

Answer (score 3):

Create a callback on the Activity onBackPressed that the View class will implement

Example

```
public void interface onBackPressedHandler {

   public void onBackPressed();
}
```

**Activity Class**

```
public onBackPressedHandler mHandler;


@Override 
public void onCreate(....) {

   GameView game... //Inflate or create.
   game.setActivity(this);

}

public void setListener(onBackPressedHandler handler) {
    mHandler = handler;
}

@Override
public voind onBackPressed() {

  if(mHandler != null) {
       mHandler.onBackPressed();
  }
  super.onBackPressed();
```

**View Class**

```
public GameView extends View implements onBackPressedHandler {

public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
     activity.setListener(this);
}    


public void onBackPressed() {
  //your code here.
    }
}
```

This example shows when you press the back Button it will call the onBackPress on the View.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Do I need to create a new class that extends to Activity? or I will direct on the Activity class?

Comment: the View class only need access to the Activity class you dont need it to extends the Acitiviy class.

Comment: If you want to call activity.setListener(this) you would have to pass Activity to the View through constructor or cast View's Context to Activity to make setListener method visible.

Comment: sir @Loop can you give some block of codes on that? I just want to implement *onBackPressed* on a `Class` that extend `View Class`

Comment: sir @ItzikSamara Im just confused to where will I do the editing on the Activity Class that you just mentioned.

Comment: sir @ItzikSamara on your `Activity Class suggestion` where would I do the editing on that? do I need to go direct to the Android Activity Class to do the editing?

Comment: Yes you need to edit your Activity directly .. directly means add this code i wrote your Activity and GameView Classes.

Comment: This code will not work for @icecream. Every onBackPressed call will terminate Activity and the Game as well. Take a look how I deal with this in my answer.